# How to Get Mime of URL in linux

Tags: linux, url, mime

Is there any way to get the MIME TYPE of an URL file?

e.g.: http://example.com/photo.jpg

Get that is an jpg/application or similar.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try `curl -I <url>`. This should show you the the headers and especially the `Content-Type` sent by the server.

Example:

```
> curl -I "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/fd43775c1ea617f12187cab9785ef2d0?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: max-age=300
Content-Type: image/png
Date: Mon, 14 Dec 2015 09:48:41 GMT
Expires: Mon, 14 Dec 2015 09:53:41 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 08:00:00 GMT
Link: <https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/fd43775c1ea617f12187cab9785ef2d0?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1>; rel="canonical"
Server: ECS (fcn/9F89)
Source-Age: 140
Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
X-Cache: HIT
X-Varnish: 336435067 334859069
Content-Length: 768
```

Be aware that the content type sent by the server doesn't have to be the real content type.

Comment: It doesn't work for https URLs

Comment: @user3929135 : Then please extend or fix you Q. Good luck.

Comment: @user3929135 Provide a sample URL

Comment: Example: https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/fd43775c1ea617f12187cab9785ef2d0?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1